# How can I circle back to the a starting point using a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I have a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<object>> myObjects_ptrs`. I need to, starting in one of my objects, circle back again to where I started.

I am doing this as follows:

```cpp
while(true)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < myObjects_ptrs.size(); ++i)
    {
        myObjects_ptr[i]->doSomething();
        //and here I need to circle back
        for(int j = i + 1; j < myObjects_ptr.size(); ++j)
        {
            //do some things with each other object
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
        {
            //do the same things with the rest of the objects
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the standard way of doing that? My problem is that once I detect something, then I dont need to keep going around. For example if I find something during the first loop then there is no need to go through the second loop. I con solve this by adding an extra `if` before the second loop; but is there a better way?

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do. You want to `do some things` to each object *many times?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a modulus, i.e. the two inner loops would become:

```
int numObjects = myObjects_ptr.size();
for (int j = i + 1; j < numObjects + i + 1; ++j)
{
  // Get object
  auto& obj = myObjects_ptr[j % numObjects];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the two inner loops with something like this:

```
for(int j = i + 1;; j++)
{
    j %= myObjects_ptr.size();
    if (j == i)
    {
        break;
    }
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: I think there's a infinite loop bug if `i == 0`.  Say `myObjects_ptr.size()` is 5, `i == 0`.  Then `j` starts with value 1, increments to 2, 3, 4, then 5.  At 5, test `j != i` is not true, but `j == myObjects_ptr.size()`, so j is assigned to 0.  It does stuff, then foor loop repeats and increments `j` to 1 again.  A fix is to remove the `if`, and replace `j++` with `j = (j + 1) % myObjects_ptr.size` (inspired by @nitronoid).

Comment: @Perette What I ended up doing was `for (int j = i; j <= objects.size(); ++j)`, and an additional `if(j == i) break;` inside. That would solve the problem you point out. I would now test @nitronoid 's answer and see if it fits better my needs.